# Find array match and remove element

Tags: php, arrays, match

Given two arrays:

```
$arr1 = (1, 0, 9);
$arr2 = (8, 0, 2, 9, 4);
```

How can I remove the elements in `$arr2` that consists in `$arr1`?

This would return `$arr3 = (8, 2, 4);`

I've tried this:

```
<?php
foreach($arr1 as $item)
{
       if(in_array($item, $arr2))
       {
          # This is were I lose it, I've found a match then what?
       }
}
?>
```

Comment: you can use unset(array(index)); http://in2.php.net/unset

Comment: Built-in function: `array_diff` http://php.net/array_diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_diff` is what you're looking for

Take a look [here](https://www.php.net/array_diff)

```
$arr1 = array(1, 0, 9);
$arr2 = array(8, 0, 2, 9, 4);

echo print_r(array_diff($arr2,$arr1),true);

>> Array ( [0] => 8 [2] => 2 [4] => 4 )
```